# Ruby and RubyDev under Chocolately on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, chocolatey, ruby-development-kit

I have installer ruby 2.3.1 ruby.devkit 4.5.2.20120101 from the chocolately repostory on windows 10

then i have modified conf.yml and run:

```
PS C:\tools\DevKit> ruby dk.rb install --force
[WARN] Updating (with backup) existing gem override for 'C:/tools/ruby23'
[WARN] Updating (with backup) DevKit helper library for 'C:/tools/ruby23'
```

All seem to me ok, but when I try to update gems, some of them show the following errors:

```
PS C:\tools\DevKit> gem update
Updating installed gems
Updating bigdecimal
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bigdecimal:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.0/ext/bigdecimal
C:/tools/ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170106-4004-rogg3v.rb extconf.rb
checking for labs() in stdlib.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/tools/ruby23/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:765:in `try_func'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1051:in `block in have_func'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1050:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/bigdecimal-1.3.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bigdecimal-1.3.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/bigdecimal-1.3.0/gem_make.out
Updating did_you_mean
ERROR:  Error installing did_you_mean:
        did_you_mean requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0dev.
Updating io-console
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing io-console:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/io-console-0.4.6
C:/tools/ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170106-4004-impy5k.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/tools/ruby23/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:524:in `with_werror'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:835:in `macro_defined?'
        from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/io-console-0.4.6/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/io-console-0.4.6 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/io-console-0.4.6/gem_make.out
Updating json
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.0.2/ext/json/ext/generator
C:/tools/ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170106-4004-dmzeq3.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.0.2/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.0.2/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
generating generator-x64-mingw32.def
compiling generator.c
make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [generator.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/json-2.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/json-2.0.2/gem_make.out
Updating psych
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing psych:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/psych-2.2.2/ext/psych
C:/tools/ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170106-4004-1rx9fhh.rb extconf.rb
checking for yaml.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/tools/ruby23/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-libyaml-dir
        --without-libyaml-dir
        --with-libyaml-include
        --without-libyaml-include=${libyaml-dir}/include
        --with-libyaml-lib
        --without-libyaml-lib=${libyaml-dir}/lib
        --enable-bundled-libyaml
        --disable-bundled-libyaml
C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1144:in `block in find_header'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:942:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:350:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:320:in `open'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:346:in `postpone'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:941:in `checking_for'
        from C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:1143:in `find_header'
        from extconf.rb:10:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/psych-2.2.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/psych-2.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/psych-2.2.2/gem_make.out
Gems updated: bigdecimal did_you_mean io-console json psych
```

i realy can't understand what is happen, any idea?

Comment: Go again step by step, `ruby dk.rb init`, then `install`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part in the error messages is:

> The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
>   You have to install development tools first.

In order to install compiled gems, you need a compiler installed. For Windows, you can install the [Ruby DeveloperKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/).

While you have it installed apparently, it doesn't seem to be recognized. This can have one of various reasons, the most common being the devkit not matching your ruby version or issues with the `%PATH`.

Comment: it is installed, and patch seem to be correct, che installation of devkit didn't show errors

Comment: Well, DevKit 4.5.2.20120101 is **really** old. It seems this package on chocolatey isn't updated much... Please try to download and install a newer version of the DevKit from the link I posted in my answer.

Comment: thx you so much, i overwrite with the new version and it is work!
just did_you_mean do some error but it is not a problem :)
Updating did_you_mean
ERROR:  Error installing did_you_mean:
        did_you_mean requires Ruby version >= 2.4.0dev.

Comment: The `did_you_mean` gem is shipped with ruby itself and is often specific to the installed ruby version. It does not need to be updated. The error you get is because the latest version of this gem requires Ruby 2.4 (an is shipped with it).

Comment: The problem here is that the OP was attempting to install the wrong package. ruby.devkit is for Ruby 1.8/1.9 only, as noted in my answer. @halon is looking for ruby2.devkit. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41524499/18475

Comment: I would have edited your answer but it would have completely changed your answer.

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr - you should install `ruby2.devkit` instead.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511890/18475 answer, it says that the ruby.devkit package is out of date. It's not, it just applies to a different Ruby.

### Incorrect Package

You maybe missed this from https://chocolatey.org/packages/ruby.devkit: [image: Ruby DevKit (1.8 & 1.9)]

As opposed to Ruby v2 DevKit (https://chocolatey.org/packages/ruby2.devkit):
[image: Ruby DevKit (2.0+)]

You installed the incorrect package - https://chocolatey.org/packages/ruby2.devkit is the one you are looking for.

The compiler changed for Ruby v2+ for Ruby on Windows, which means you need to use the proper compilers. That DevKit is in the `ruby2.devkit` package.

### Don't Forget to Refresh Your Environment

If you are using Chocolatey, you get `refreshenv` as a command you can call in cmd.exe or powershell.exe (With PowerShell, be sure you have tab completion in your profile so that the proper `refreshenv` is available).

Otherwise you will need to close and reopen your shell for the updated PATHs to happen.

### More Details

Head out to http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/:

[image: Different DevKits]

### More Fun With Ruby

Here's a gist that does a complete Ruby stack setup: https://gist.github.com/ferventcoder/947479688d930e28d632

It's a bit outdated, so here is an update (PowerShell):

```
# https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsReference#how-to-pass-options--switches 
# Powershell specific argument passing
# You must be on the latest beta of chocolatey for this to work properly (redownload files)

choco upgrade chocolatey -y

$originalPath = $env:PATH

choco install ruby --version 2.1.8 -my -x86 --install-arguments '/verysilent /dir=""c:\tools\ruby21"" /tasks=""assocfiles""' --override-arguments
choco install ruby --version 2.1.8 -fmy --install-arguments '/verysilent /dir=""c:\tools\ruby21-x64"" /tasks=""assocfiles""' --override-arguments
choco install ruby --version 2.3.1 -my -x86 --install-arguments '/verysilent /dir=""c:\tools\ruby23"" /tasks=""assocfiles""' --override-arguments
choco install ruby --version 2.3.1 -fmy --install-arguments '/verysilent /dir=""c:\tools\ruby23-x64"" /tasks=""assocfiles,modpath""' --override-arguments

Write-Output "Attempting Good DevKit2 Installations"
# DevKit for Ruby 2.x x64
$env:PATH=$originalPath
choco install ruby2.devkit -y 
Move-Item c:\tools\DevKit2 C:\tools\DevKit2-x64 -Force -EA Continue

# DevKit for Ruby 2.x x86
choco install ruby2.devkit -y -x86 -f

Write-Output "Fixing DevKit Installations"

@"
---
- c:/tools/ruby21
- c:/tools/ruby23
"@ | Out-File c:\tools\DevKit2\config.yml -Force -Encoding UTF8
pushd c:\tools\DevKit2
ruby dk.rb install -f
popd

@"
---
- c:/tools/ruby21-x64
- c:/tools/ruby23-x64
"@ | Out-File c:\tools\DevKit2-x64\config.yml -Force -Encoding UTF8
pushd c:\tools\DevKit2-x64
ruby dk.rb install -f
popd

choco install pik -y

cmd /c C:\tools\pik\pik.bat add c:\tools\ruby21\bin
cmd /c C:\tools\pik\pik.bat add c:\tools\ruby21-x64\bin
cmd /c C:\tools\pik\pik.bat add c:\tools\ruby23\bin
cmd /c C:\tools\pik\pik.bat add c:\tools\ruby23-x64\bin
```